# How to give data access in cloud firestore to another added users in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I wanna ask about the concept and logically ways to give another user the privilege to access other's users' data. What I want to do exactly is like this :
[image]

Basically, collection 1 contains several Users ID (UID) from authentication, then the user will have their own data collected in collection 2 which contain the data ID.

So, it's like giving access to another user to collaborate with the data like Google Docs Apps where we can add another user to edit our documents. I've been thinking of how to do this, but still, I got stuck.

My question is, how can I possibly do this? cause from what I've read, cloud firestore don't use such a foreign key like MySQL. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

haven't tried something like this but i think this approch overcomes your problem.

[image]

modify your structure according to above image. userID collection will contain userIds which are allowed to edit their parent collection.and create firestore rules according to your use to check weather the userId is allowed to edit the Collection or not.

in your case when 'user 2' will have reference to 'collection 2',  he/she will try to change data. firebase rule will check if auth.userId is inside the 'collection2.UserIDs' or not and will allow according that.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, I will definitely try this @Jeet Chhatrala